# Need to upload both JSON and image file with Curl

Tags: json, django, curl, http-post, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST API, that has a model with `logo` tag in it, which is a file (`ImageField`). How should the `curl` command look this way. I tried this way, but it never worked for me:

```
curl -vX POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/ -d test.json --header "Conten-Type: application/json" -F "logo=@Downloads/trello.png"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately JSON does not support uploading binary files, that is currently limited to multipart requests. If you do not need to send nested data, and you are not locked to JSON, I'd recommend using that.

A workaround is to create a new view for uploading files, separate from the view that requires JSON. It won't work in all situations, and will require a two step process, but it also isolates your issue.

The other option is to create (or find) a custom field which will support JSON uploads, typically using base64 encoded strings.